# Validação de 2 campos em uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, comparação

Tenho uma tabela no Mysql, com um campo DESCRIÇÃO e outro Grau, como eu faço para que o conjunto dos dois campos não possam ser repetidos?

EXEMPLO

Se for:

DESCRIÇÃO: abcde GRAU: 12345 OK

E se for:

DESCRIÇÃO: abcde GRAU: 67891 OK

Mas se for:

DESCRIÇÃO: abcde GRAU: 12345 NÃO

Entenderam? tipo, dois campos não podem ser repedidos juntos, mas um pode.

Comment: Não, não entendi. O terceiro exemplo é `: adcde` que é diferente dos dois primeiros

Comment: Sabe o que é uma chave primária originada de duas ou mais colunas?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo kk vc ta certo, eu escrevi errado corrigi ja

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não sei, como funciona?

Comment: Mas você quer verificar se já existe na tabela algum registro conforme seus exemplos? Mais fácil que tirar doce da mão de criança na padaria!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode definir múltiplas colunas como sua chave primária, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (ID,LastName)
);
```

Assim o `ID` e o `LastaName` podem repetir mas não podem repetir juntos

Comment: Vlw cara! de vdd tava a mto temo procurando isso

Comment: A pergunta é `descricao` e `grau` que não podem repetir. No caso do `id` ter que ser AUTO_INCREMENT e descricao e grau não puderem repetir, não vai rolar. Já que vc não adaptou o script para corresponder a pergunta, acho pertinente postar a fonte desse script

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo utilizar um select para averiguar se existe tais parametros previamente cadastrados, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT count(desc) as 'qtdDesc' FROM table WHERE desc = 'descAserInserida' AND grau = 'grauAserInserido';
```

Depois é só verificar se 'qtdDesc' > 0, então não cadastra, senão você cadastra.

> **como uso isso na hora de inserir dados na tabela?**
>
> Usa da seguinte forma, exemplo com `mysqli`

```
$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "nome_DB");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT count(descricao) as 'qtdDesc' FROM table WHERE descricao = '$descAserInserida' AND grau = '$grauAserInserido'");

$row = $result->fetch_row();
if ($row[0] > 0) {
    //existe, não insere
    echo "existe";
} else {
    echo "não existe";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (descricao,grau) VALUES('$descAserInserida','$grauAserInserido')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: como uso isso na hora de inserir dados na tabela?

Comment: A ideia não é agrupar os resultados, e sim não permitir duplicata de linhas, acredito que entendeu errado a pergunta, ou então eu que entendi muito mal

Comment: Ah, o GROUP BY apenas agrupa os resultados, no caso da inserção de dados você pode realizar um select como: SELECT count(desc) as 'qtdDesc' FROM table WHERE desc = 'descAserInserida' AND grau = 'grauAserInserido'; e verificar se qtdDesc > 0, se for você não cadastra, e se não for você cadastra..